# How to pass Date as Parameter from controller to API?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have Controller :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/360ScoreCard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Object get360ScoreCard(@RequestParam("userEmail") String userEmail,
        @RequestParam("valid_from") String from, @RequestParam("valid_till") String till) throws ParseException {

    if (userEmail != null) {
        String uri = util.getRestApiHost() + "userScoreFor360" + "?userEmail=" + userEmail;

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date valid_from = (Date) formatter.parse(from);
        Date valid_till = (Date) formatter.parse(till);

        MultiValueMap<String, Date> paramMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Date>();
        paramMap.add("valid_from", valid_from);
        paramMap.add("valid_till", valid_till);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, paramMap, Response.class);
        return response;
    }
    return "User Email is Null";
}
```

I have API:-

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userScoreFor360", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object getScoreFor360( @RequestParam String userEmail,Date valid_from, Date valid_till, HttpServletResponse initResponse) {
    logger.debug("Enter into method getScoreFor360()");
    Response response=new Response();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        response = scoreService.get360Score(userEmail,valid_from,valid_till);
        Feedback360 fbThreeSixty = (Feedback360) response.getResult();
        List<ThreeSixtyRatings> listOfRating = fbThreeSixty.getRating_list();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (ThreeSixtyRatings ratings : listOfRating) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("category", ratings.getCategory());
            json.put("rating_average", ratings.getRating_average());
            json.put("number_feedbacks", ratings.getNumber_feedbacks());
            jsonArray.put(json);
        }
        obj.put("rating_list", jsonArray);
        obj.put("aggregate", fbThreeSixty.getAggregate());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in userScoreFor360 Mobile Api :", e);
    } 
    logger.debug("Exit from method getScoreFor360()" + new Gson().toJson(response));
    return obj.toString();
}
```

I want to pass Date from Controller to API. Whenever i am trying to pass the Date from controller to API, it is throwing exception:-

```
2019-06-24 15:15:34.437  WARN 2672 --- [nio-8180-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '1516300200000'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

I am not able to understand that even after adding the Dates to MultivalueMap where it is of Date type, how it is API is treating Date as String type?

Please Note:- I cannot change the API.

Comment: hi @Nikant, and I assume this API working from other calls, considering you can't change right?

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `@RequestParam`, but also if you need to consume as a `Date` you can do

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/userScoreFor360", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object getScoreFor360( @RequestParam String userEmail, 
                              @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date valid_from,
                              @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date valid_till, 
                              HttpServletResponse initResponse) {

    //LOGIC

    return obj.toString();
}
```

or only way to consume valid_from and valid_to as `String` and format it to date using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Hey Avi, if you look in his example .. he is not passing the date in the RequestParam, it is passing in the body.

Comment: Hey @Brother, you can pass Form data as `Map` and the resttemplate will consider that as query param, So the `@RequestMapping` logic will work . If you look at the `postForObject` (Source code), to be specific `doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest httpRequest)`  this method is responsible for deciding whether the request is a `Body` or `FormData`, So when you do not pass a proper `Class` or an `Object` this will be considered as a `FormData` and will be written as a `Param`. That magic is done by `FormHttpMessageConverter`.  Look into it

Comment: Cool, I asked if he really cant change .. because he said in the description he cant change the api.